# "That's a good question" as a response to an inquiry

Tags: meaning, expressions

Why does the person being spoken to say "that's a good question".  Is this response a form of condescension?

Comment: I would say it is the opposite of condescension.  Condescension would be "That's a dumb question."

Comment: It seems to vary. I've heard it used as a filler, when someone asks a hard question - saying it gives you time to think of an answer. It can be used in evasion, where you praise the question to avoid having to answer it. Or it might be sarcastic.

Comment: Basically, it's a polite response which provides no information to a question. It's also a polite request to not ask again. If you're still curious, you have been warned there are limits.

Comment: The question [When should I say or write the expression, "Good question"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/275778/191178) seems like it covers all the uses pretty well.

Comment: @Laurel, the question is a duplicate of that one, but I am reluctant to vote to close it as such, because the other one is closed, and at least one question on this matter ought to remain open. The question should not be closed as not showing research either, because it is about the subtleties of usage that go beyond dictionary definitions.

Comment: @jsw29 reasonably argued. Leave open.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a condescension.

**good question** (idiom)

> Used to say that one doesn't know the answer to a question
>
> *How can we reduce expenses without cutting important programs?*
>
> *(That's a) good question.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good%20question)

> If you say 'Good question' in reply to a question, you mean that it is
> a difficult question to answer, or perhaps that you are embarrassed
> about the answer or do not know the answer.
>
> [*spoken*]
> 'Why didn't you appoint Ron twelve months ago?'—'Good
> question.' [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/good-question)

> **that's a good question**, often altered to **a very good question** or shortened to **a good question!** or simply **good
> question!** That's a sensible or shrewd or very pertinent question;
> often as a time-gainer when one's seeking for an answer to an
> extremely difficult question; indeed it often implies "That's a
> question I can't solve', since the middle ot late 1940s, but not very
> common before c. 1955. From radio and TV 'panels' and 'quizzes'.
> J.W.C., 1977 notes that it is 'usually, in the US, followed by the mendacious and dilatory stop-gap, "I'm (very) glad you asked it'" ... [Eric
> Partridge; *A Dictionary of Catch Phrases*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Dictionary_of_Catch_Phrases/YcWHAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22that%27s%20a%20good%20question%22&pg=PA451&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

Comment: I note it can also be used to stall while collecting your thoughts to give a real answer.

Comment: I agree, and it can also be a way of announcing *I don't have a definitive answer, but here is what I do know.*

Comment: It is also a good hedged staller for when the askee decides that the question is one it's not in their (or others') interest to answer. Collins almost includes this.

Comment: Perhaps it should be said that, although the phrase is not inherently condescending, it is sometimes used condescendingly. In fact, the purpose of a particular use of the phrase is impossible to discern without knowing what follows it.

Comment: At least in the UK, you can say 'That's a [very] good question' in response to a question about a potentially controversial topic, and where e.g. there is more than one possible answer. Q: What caused the big IT failure last week? A: That's a good question. It was either the contractor's fault, or our CEO deleted some vital files.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think the basic intent of "That's a (very) good question" can be seen in what follows. When a well-known expert says it, it may be followed by a short summary of possible answers/schools of thought, and, in the sciences, perhaps an experiment, equipment, research being built/done to answer the question.  Frankness, "I/we don't know" followed by thoughts/opinions also helps, IMO.

Comment: yes. I meant to imply that in my imagined usage, there is a correct answer and an 'official' one. Or officially 'nobody knows' but unofficially everybody does.